# GroupBy loses ThenBy sort order

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

How do I build an expression that will preserve the ThenBy order?
The Expression below produces the Groups ordered by Bowler.Number but the Matches of each group are not sorted.

```
public class Match
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Bowler Bowler { get; set; }
   public byte GameNumber { get; set; }
   public int Score { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Bowler
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set;}
   ...
}

var GroupedMatches = db.Matches.OrderBy(m=>m.Bowler.Number).ThenBy(m=>m.GameNumber).GroupBy(m => m.Bowler.Number)
```

Here is the output I want:

```
1
  game1 295
  game2 199
  game3 202
  game4 178
2
  game1 177
  ...
```

Current I use two foreach like

```
foreach (var item in TheGroups){
    ... do some stuff with the Group
    foreach (var x in item.OrderBy(a =>a.Number)) { //<-- can I get rid of this OrderBy?
    ... do some stuff with the Matches in this group
   }
}
```

No big deal, I just thought LINQ would be able to help me sort the matches in the group when the groups where built, not later when I process them.

Comment: You're grouping without concern for `GameNumber` so you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want the output to be, since it's kind of non-sensical to order a list of groups keyed on bowler number by game number.

Assuming you want an ordered list of bowler numbers, each containing an ordered list of games, something like this might work

```
var GroupedMatches = db.Matches
    .GroupBy(m => m.Bowler.Number)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select (g => new 
            { 
                BowlerNumber = g.Key, 
                Matches = g.OrderBy(m => m.GameNumber).ToList() 
            });
```

Here's specifically how you get the output you're looking for

```
foreach(var group in GroupedMatches) {
    Console.WriteLine(group.BowlerNumber);
    foreach(var match in group.Matches) {
        Console.WriteLine("game{0} {1}", match.GameNumber, match.Score);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get two compiler errors where I try and 'foreach' the results.  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'AnonymousType#1' because 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' and  'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' ..

Comment: If you want to `foreach` on each group, foreach on `group.Matches`.

Comment: I need to foreach both the Groups and the Matches. I've edited my question to the output I want and what I do now to get it.

Comment: @Pablo:  I've updated my answer to show you exactly how to loop over the result to get the output you want.

Comment: Excellent ...  thanks a million for your help (and patience)!